# Multiple 'GET' Forms in one Django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to use multiple "get" forms in one view?
Let's say I have forms:

`<form> {{form1}} <button>Send1</button> </form>`

`<form> {{form2}} <button>Send2</button> </form>`

Now if I click on 'Send1' I will lose information about form with 'Send2' button because url will change

In other words - How to proper set forms with get method so the data will combine in the url

Comment: If you want to submit `form1` data without losing `form2` data, or without changing the URL or refreshing the page, you can use `AJAX` to submit the data separately.

Answer (score 0):

You combine the two Django forms as a single HTML form:

```
<form> {{form1}} <button>Send1</button> 
       {{form2}} <button>Send2</button> 
</form>
```

You'll need to embellish the buttons a bit if you need to know which was clicked. Give them different names or values.

In Django, you can work out which button was pressed by examining `request.GET`.

If any of the form field names overlap, you can use the `prefix` argument to dis-ambiguate them. Or possibly, what you want is actually one form with two submit buttons.